Issue when trying to attach a txt file in a JIRA ticket using Invoke-RestMethod in Powershell
I would like to attach a small txt file in an existing JIRA ticket by the help of the command Invoke-RestMethod - POST  in Powershell
Here after the code (file Test_JTR_post_transition.ps1):
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory,HelpMessage='JIRA ID')] [String]$jiraID
)

write-host jiraID = $jiraID

$base64AuthInfo = Get-Content ($psScriptRoot + "\config\s_asa_tech_base64.txt")

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$jiraRestUrl = "http://xxxxxxx/jira/rest/api/2"

function put-attachedfile(){
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$jiraID
  )

  $attfile = "export.txt"
  
  $result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType "multipart/form-data" -infile $attfile -uri "$jiraRestUrl/issue/$jiraID/attachments" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
  return $result
  write-host result = $result
}

$status = put-attachedfile -jiraID $jiraID
return $status


I run the ps1 file as followed :
PS D:\Scripts\eventCreation> .\Test_JTR_post_transition.ps1 -jiraID OASSBISAS-10414

And I got the following messages :
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At D:\Scripts\eventCreation\Test_JTR_post_transition.ps1:41 char:12
+   $result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -infile $attfile -ContentTy ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand


Are you sure the base url is correct? It isn't "http://xxxxxxx/rest/api/2" as opposed to "http://xxxxxxx/jira/rest/api/2"? Additionally, try passing -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo); 'X-Atlassian-Token'= 'no-check'}

Actually I have put xxxxxxx instead of the real value for a question of confidentiality. Anyway I'm going to test what you propose. Thanks.

it's not the xxxxxxx part I was wondering about, it's the /jira/ part :)

It looks like the URI you are using resolves to a path that doesn't exist.
Based on JIRA Service Desk REST API Reference it looks like the URI for uploading an attachment to a ticket, looks a bit like this:
/rest/servicedeskapi/request/{issueIdOrKey}/attachment
It might be different based on environments, but this is as close as I could get it based on the provided information.
Suggest you try editing these two lines:
$jiraRestUrl = "http://xxxxxxx/jira/rest/api/2"

"$jiraRestUrl/issue/$jiraID/attachments"

To:
$jiraRestUrl = "http://xxxxxxx/rest/servicedeskapi/request/"

"$jiraRestUrl/$jiraID/attachment/"

Maybe you need to play around a bit with the API to figure out what works, maybe start by just retrieving a ticket based on the Jira Ticket ID?
Edit: I found another page with another example for creating a comment with an attachment. Maybe this is even more accurate for your use-case?
It uses almost identical URI to what I posted, but has an additional URI for adding the attachment with a comment:
Create comment with attachment

Hello Mark. Thank you for your reply. I'm going to take care about what you suggest and the link you mention.
